# how can I set the threshold cursor velocity for passing through the Ubuntu menu bar?

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, menu

I am running with dual monitors (left and right) via ATI Catalyst `Display Manager`, not Xinerama.  Both monitors have a vertical Ubuntu menu bar on the left.  I probably do not need each monitor to have one because it is a waste of space but I will live with it for the time being.

As a feature, the cursor will not "easily" pass through the Ubuntu menu bar when going from the left to the right monitor and vice versa.  It will pass through only if the cursor is traveling at a high velocity.  Can I lower the threshold velocity and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the value of `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/stop_velocity` to `1` in gconf, using `gconf-editor` or `gconftool-2`, it will give you the desired result. You would have to be moving the mouse extremely slowly to have it stop, with this setting. The minimum allowed value for this setting is 1, so setting it to 0 won't do.